# Printing 2 hash maps next to each other

Tags: java, hashmap, printf

```
public static void printingCharacters(Map<Character, Integer> m,Map <Character, Integer> m1) {
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> countedArray : m.entrySet()) {
                System.out.printf("Letter: %c :  Time occurs: %d -  %.2f %%\t\t\t Letter: %c :  Time occurs: %d -  %.2f %%\n ", countedArray.getKey(),
                        countedArray.getValue(), percentageOfOccurrence(countedArray.getValue())
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------|  \t|-----------------------------------------------------|");

            }
        }
```

I am having a method that accepts 2 hash maps as parameter and I want to print the hash maps next to each other so I use a for loop which goes through the first one and prints the content I need it to print.Then I use a printf statement in order to show the results in console.After \t\t\t in printf (second table on the picture) I want to print the same content but for map m1 I am not sure how to do this.If anyone can give me a hint that would be awesome :).

P.S In the end I want to achieve something like this.Where table 1 is m table 2 is m1

[image]

Comment: how does your `HashMap` contain multiple `Integer values` with same `Character key 'y'` ?

Comment: This is because I made a for loop inside the for loop and it bugged the results .Everything works fine I just don't know how to make a method which will print the both hashmaps like shown on the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using Iterators :

```
public static void printingCharacters(Map<Character, Integer> m, Map <Character, Integer> m1) {    
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> it = m.entrySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> it1 = m1.entrySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext() && it1.hasNext()) {
        printEntries(it.next(), it1.next());
    }
}

public static void printEntries(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e1) {
    System.out.printf("Letter: %c :  Time occurs: %d -  %.2f %%\t\t\t Letter: %c :  Time occurs: %d -  %.2f %%\n ", e.getKey(),
            e.getValue(), percentageOfOccurrence(e.getValue()), e1.getKey(), e1.getValue(), percentageOfOccurrence(e1.getValue()));
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------|  \t|-----------------------------------------------------|");
}
```